# How can I install daemon on a CentOS box?

Tags: centos, daemon, solr

I'm basically looking for the equivalent of :

> sudo apt-get install daemon

From Debian

I'm trying to configure a Solr daemon as outlined here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2150888/443779

Comment: You can write your own init script for solr like this one:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420127/daemon-for-solr

Comment: Another way is to use a tanuki-wrapper, that's available in the CentOS/RHEL repos, IIRC.

Comment: @deagh that is again a Debian style init script and won't work on CentOS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't believe you can get the Debian style `daemon` to work in CentOS, in CentOS it is more common to source `/etc/init.d/functions` in your init script.
This will make the daemon *function* available to you - with totally different options than the example you posted!

For a simple example check out the `crond` init script at `/etc/init.d/crond`.